# Installing a bot in Microsoft teams, the bot name is the Azure host not the bot name specified in the mandate

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have deployed a custom app in teams, which is an Azure hosted bot framework chatbot. To install I used teams "App Studio" app, where under "Bots" I selected my existing bot. I deployed to a specific team. Everything works perfectly, apart from the actual name of the bot in teams. Instead of the user being able to start a chat with the chatbot name @Dave, they have to start using the Azure host name @prodserver123. Anychats with the bot then display the bot messages as coming from @prodserver123.

I have gone through the manifest, the chatbot name is specified as @Dave everywhere, and the BotId on Azure is also @Dave.

Does anybody know how I might be able to resolve this please?

Answer (score 2):

For sidealoaded apps Bot name and icon is taken from Bot Service. For apps which are published in Teams App Store, the Bot informatin is fetched from app manifest.

Also, Bot names are cached and that could be the reason you don't see updated name. Please sign out and sign in to clear out the cache.